# Добавляет несколько копий

Tags: php, html, массивы, sqlite

запрос

```
function saveNews($title, $category, $description, $source) {
    $dt = time();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO msgs(title, category, description, source, datetime) VALUES ('$title', $category, '$description', '$source', $dt)";
    return $res = $this->_db->exec($sql);
  }
```

добавление

```
 $title = $news->clearStr($_POST["title"]);
    $description = $news->clearStr($_POST["description"]);
    $source = $news->clearStr($_POST["source"]);
    $category = $news->clearInt($_POST["category"]);
    if (empty($title) or empty($description)) {
      $errMSG = "Заполните все поля формы";
    } else {
      if (!$news->saveNews($title, $category, $description, $source)) {
        $errMSG = "Ошибка при добавлении новости";
      } else {
        header("Location: news.php");
        exit;
      }
    }
```

Cама форма

```
 <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Заголовок новости:
        <br />
    <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
    Выберите категорию:
        <br />
    <select name="category">
      <option value="1">Политика</option>
      <option value="2">Культура</option>
      <option value="3">Спорт</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    Текст новости:
        <br />
    <textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
        <br />
    Источник:
        <br />
    <input type="text" name="source" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить!" />
</form>
```

добавляю в массив

Проблема в том, что в массив добавляются одинаковые данные, только с разными  данными из Select. То есть примено так выглядит

```
$arr = [[
  "title" => "Лавро передал привет",
  "category" => "Политика",
  "description" => "blablablabla",
  "source" => "ABC"
],[
  "title" => "Лавро передал привет",
  "category" => "Cпорт",
  "description" => "blablablabla",
  "source" => "ABC"
],[
  "title" => "Лавро передал привет",
  "category" => "Культура",
  "description" => "blablablabla",
  "source" => "ABC"
]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, есть ли javascript обработчик формы. Атрибут `obsubmit` у формы или `onclick` у кнопки отправки. Возможно, в проекте используется jquery. Тогда обработчик выглядит `$('form').submit(...)` или `$('form').on('submit', ...)`
Возможно, он отправляет форму несколько раз.

Удалите этот обработчик.

Comment: переписал заново запрос, уже все нормально отправляет, js не применяется